# How would I redirect a null reference from this code to a different page

Tags: c#

I am brand new to c# and am currently modifying code. This is the code that I have:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkMember("Challenge", "answerQuestion.gif");

    var pagenameTemp = Session["RequestedPage"].ToString();
    var pagename = pagenameTemp.Substring(0, pagenameTemp.IndexOf('.'));
    var node = Settings.getNode("Challenge/HighRisk");
```

I want to be able to redirect the null reference that I'm getting on:

```
var pagenameTemp = Session["RequestedPage"].ToString();
```

to a new page. I've tried different if statements and have yet to be successful.

Comment: Is `Session["RequestedPage"]` a null reference? If that's the case the problem is up-stream from your page..

Comment: What do you mean you want to "redirect the null reference?"

Comment: Please show the `if` statements you've tried, it will be easier to understand.

Comment: I'm guessing that the OP wants to avoid showing exception messages in the browser, but instead show an "error" page?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that Session["RequestedPage"] COULD be null, so executing a .ToString() on a null object will cause it to fail.

You should do something like this...

```
var pagenameTemp = (Session["RequestedPage"] == null) ? 
    "SomeErrorPage.aspx" : Session["RequestedPage"].ToString();
```